# Run GTK# Application in Kiosk Mode

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, kiosk-mode

I am writing a C#/Mono app (GTK# GUI) for the Raspberry Pi. I want to run this app in kiosk mode (fullscreen, no metacity/ window borders, unable to exit). How does this work under Linux/Raspian? In Windows using WPF I can simply set the Window borderless and maximize it. I havn´t found a similar Property on the GTK-Window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on OS-X, but I do not have a Linux box to double-check it right now, but it should be the same:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace GtkfullscreenNotdecorated
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            win.Fullscreen ();
            win.Decorated = false;
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing is win.Fullscreen. In full screen, GTK2 window decoration is not visible, but I always add it. Run it with and without performing the win.Fullscreen() to see how your display manager is turning the decoration off.